# Picker Selected item becoming null in Listview

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, picker

I am doing an application in which i have a picker as item inside a list.The selected item is turned to null once the list view is scrollup and then scroll down.Can anyone please help me in solving this issue.I am doing this in Xamarin.Forms for iOS app.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have gone through this link- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2751 .There i found the reason is because the picker selected item gets reset during PropertyChangedEvent. Can anyone please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Please post your code so we can try to help you. Are you checking if the selected item property is being reset?

Comment: Thanks for your respose Bruno. I have checked it.The Selected item property is not resetting.Can you please help me in solving this. I am using xamarin.forms version 2.4.0.282 .And also I tried updating the xamarin forms package to latest version.But it did not worked.